# How does this prettyDate function work? Seems like it has multiple return values

Tags: javascript

I saw this code snippet in the Smashing Node book that adapts John Resig's prettyDate function. I don't see how the function can return a string back when it clearly seems to be a boolean value.

```
Date.prototype.__defineGetter__('ago', function () {
    var diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - this.getTime()) / 1000)
    , day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);
    return day_diff == 0 && (
        diff < 60 && "just now" ||
        diff < 120 && "1 minute ago" ||
        diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " minutes ago" ||
        diff < 7200 && "1 hour ago" ||
        diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " hours ago") ||
        day_diff == 1 && "Yesterday" ||
        day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days ago" ||
        Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " weeks ago";
});

var a = new Date('11/05/1989');
console.log(a.ago); // outputs '1264 weeks ago'
```

Comment: Look up "short-circuit operators".

Comment: that it "clearly seems to be a boolean value" is, like "==" a "false cognate" to other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators `||` and `&&` do not strictly return boolean values in Javascript.

`x || y` evaluates to `x` if it is truthy, otherwise `y`; `x && y` evaluates to `x` if it is falsy, otherwise `y`. Therefore both of them can result in any type of value.

You will see this type of usage put to use in several scenarios, for example assigning default values to arguments, for example:

```
// not the best example, but makes the point
function increment(i, step) {
    return i + (step || 1);
}
```

or even

```
function firstNonZero(a, b, c) {
    return a || b || c || null;
}
```